# Git tag on previous commit

Tags: git

Ok so I'm running into an issue or maybe not and I just don't understand.

What I am doing is trying to commit and push the commit but also tag it.

I'm doing this from gulp running shell commands though so that might have something to do with it,

`git add [files]`

`git commit -m [message]`

`git tag -a [tag name] [branch] -m [message]`

and then

`git push origin [tag name]`

But issue is that tag is pushed on a previous commit instead of what I am currently committing.

My current gulp task looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
plugin = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  camelize: true
}),
ghPages = require('gulp-gh-pages'),
run = require('gulp-run'),
prompt = require('gulp-prompt');

module.exports = function() {
 console.log('Deployment is running currently, please be patient.');

 return gulp.src('modules/**/*')
  .pipe(ghPages({
    remoteUrl: '[user]@[ip]:[branch]',
    branch: '[branch]'
  }))
  .on('end', function() {
    return gulp.src('modules/**/*')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
      type: 'input',
      name: 'release',
      message: 'Is this a new release? (y/n)',
    }, function( res ) {
      if ( res.release == 'y' ) {
        return gulp.src('modules/**/*', {
            read: false
          })
          .pipe(prompt.prompt({
            type: 'input',
            name: 'releaseNumber',
            message: 'What is the new release version number? (e.g. x.x.x)'
          }, function( res ) {
            run('git fetch --all').exec();
            run('git tag -a v' + res.releaseNumber + ' [branch] -m "Bump release"').exec();
            run('git push origin v' + res.releaseNumber + ' [branch]').exec();
          }));
      }
    }));
});
};
```

What is output in the console is:

```
Deployment is running currently, please be patient.
[16:12:28] [gh-pages (branch)] Cloning repo
[16:12:28] [gh-pages (branch)] Checkout remote branch `branch`
[16:12:28] [gh-pages (branch)] Updating repository
[16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Copying files to repository
[16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Adding 1 files.
[16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Committing "Update 2016-11-09T21:12:18.579Z"
[16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Pushing to remote.
[16:12:30] Finished 'deploy' after 12 s
[16:12:30] Finished 'build' after 15 s
? Is this a new release? (y/n) y
? What is the new release version number? (e.g. x.x.x) 0.0.5
$ git tag -a v0.0.5 branch -m "Bump release"
$ git push origin v0.0.5
To [user]@[ip]:[repo]
  * [new tag]         v0.0.5 -> v0.0.5
```

[image: Commit log]

As you can see from the image, the tag isn't being put on the newest commit that I am currently committing.  It is adding it to the previous commit.

I'm also in `master` pushing to another [branch].  Maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: `git tag` doesn't create a commit.

Comment: right.  it creates the tag.  the commit is already created and pushed at this line `[16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Adding 1 files. [16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Committing "Update 2016-11-09T21:12:18.579Z" [16:12:29] [gh-pages (branch)] Pushing to remote.`

Comment: So you are pushing to `lexicon-modules`? Doesn't that create a fast-forward merge commit and therefore new hash? Try to replicate it with git commands without your gulpfile.

Comment: I just tried with the git commands based on your answer and it doesn't push to branch i'm not on.  It pushes the tag but not the commit.  I'm on master doing the changes then I need to push them to a different branch without checking out that branch.

Answer (score 2):

You should show a working example of the problem. Here is a demo where it all works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

init() {
    git init --bare demo.git
    git clone --quiet demo.git demo
}

commit_line () {
    echo $1 > file
    git add file
    git commit -m "$2"
}

init
pushd demo
commit_line one first
commit_line two second
git tag -a -m "tag msg" tag-name HEAD
git push origin master tag-name
```

Running that script to create a `demo.git` bare repository and a `demo` working folder. After running this I run the following:

```
pat@here ~/tmp/demo.git $ git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --oneline
* 06a067a (HEAD -> master, tag: tag-name) second
* daa72b4 first
```

So the tag has been correctly associated with the most recent commit which is also the tip of `master` and currenly also `HEAD`. In the working folder it looks similar except we get to also see the local master matches the upstream repository.

```
pat@here ~/tmp/demo $ git graph
* 06a067a (HEAD -> master, tag: tag-name, origin/master) second
* daa72b4 first
```

Comment: updated original question.  sorry for not including everything.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed commands from your gulpfile, and run below commands on my machine

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jkulak/git-test
$ cd git-test/
$ touch first-file
$ git add first-file
$ git commit -m "Create first commit"
$ touch second-file
$ git add second-file
$ git commit -m "Create second commit"
$ git tag -a tag1 master -m "Creating first tag after second commit"
$ git push origin master
$ git push origin tag1
```

When I look on GitHub, I see:

1. https://github.com/jkulak/git-test/commits/master - second commit with hash `7008d2d`
2. https://github.com/jkulak/git-test/releases - tag1 pointing to `7008d2d`

Both are pointing to/have the same hash/commit.

So what you wrote "tag is pushed on a previous commit instead of what I am currently committing." does not seem to be the truth - can please double check that please?

I also didn't understand your last sentence - would you mind clarifying?

Also after pushing, just to be sure

```
$ git log
* 7008d2d (HEAD -> master, tag: tag1, origin/master) Create second commit
* b6d13c4 Creted first commit
```

It looks good locally as well.

Comment: updated question with illustrations and also removed the last sentence as it was confusing lol.  sorry